# Как записать число в переменную, что бы после следующего запуска программы, переменная была с числом которое мы ввели при первом запуске python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет, я делаю подобие регистрации. Как работает программа: пользователь вводит логин и пароль, после чего создается переменная i со значением 0, и создаётся цикл, который добавляет в i + 1 каждый раз когда программа запускается. Дальше этот логин и пароль записываются в файл users.py как переменные, с числом i. Как сделать так, чтобы после первого запуска программы создавалась переменная Login1, а после второго Login2? Я совсем новичок и буду рад любой критике. Заранее спасибо. Вот код:

```
userLogin = input('Login: ')
userPassword = input('Password: ')
i = 0
while True:
    i+=1
    break

with open('users.py', 'a') as file:
    file.write(f'Login{i} =' + "'" + userLogin + "'" + '\n')
    file.write(f'Password{i} =' + "'" + userPassword + "'" + '\n\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Записывай `i` в файл, при запуске читай.

Цикл `while True: i+=1 break` замени на `i += 1`.